# accumulate list based on a condition using dropWhile

Tags: scala

```
val list = List("1","10","12","30","40","50")
```

based on parameter `n` in eg `"12"` here , the elements ahead of `"12"` should form a 
    list `List("30,40,50")` and final list should be created as below

**Expected Output**
  `List("1","10","12",List("30,40,50") )`

```
list.dropWhile(_!="12").tail gives `List("30,40,50")` but i am not above the achieve the desired output
```

Comment: In `Expected Output List("1","10","12",List("30,40,50")`, you are missing a `)`, and its place can change meaning of what you do.

Comment: edited by add )

Comment: I don't understand the output format. Mixing `String` and `List[_]` is already weird enough. Do you really also want to merge `30, 40, 50` into a single string and *then* wrap it in a single-element list?

Comment: Yes  i want to do that

Answer (score 2):

`partition` will give the closest output to what you are looking for.

```
scala> list.partition(_ <= "12")
res21: (List[String], List[String]) = (List(1, 10, 12),List(30, 40, 50))
```

All elements of `List` must have the same type. `splitAt` or `partition` can accomplish this albeit with a different return type than you want. I suspect that the desired return type `List[String, ..., List[String]]` is a "type smell" that may indicate a another issue.

Comment: It will typecheck. It just will give `List[AnyRef]` or something similarly useless...

Comment: O snap. It will! Returns `List[java.io.Serializable]` which might be a little tricky to work with.

Comment: If you don't care about what's inside, and you just want to serialize and send it over network, then why not... perfectly usable. Just not what one usually wants.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `span` could help:

```
val (a, b) = list.span(_ != "12")
val h :: t = b
val res = a :+ h :+ List(t.mkString(","))
```

produces for input `List("123", "10", "12", "30", "40", "50")`:

```
List("123", "10", "12", List("30,40,50"))
```

Comment: @coder25 I've updated the answer according with the requirement that the last three elements must be merged into a single string. What part of the code requires an explanation? I've merely pointed out that there is the `span` method.

Comment: @coder25 `h :: t` creates / deconstructs a list. `h` is head, `t` is tail. E.g. `val h :: t = List(1, 2, 3)` will set `h = 1`, `t = List(2, 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you handle the output type(which is `List[java.io.Serializable]`), here is the `acc` method, which takes the desired parameter, a String `s` in this case :

```
 def acc(list:List[String],s:String) = {
       val i = list.indexOf(s)
       list.take(i+1):+List(list.drop(i+1).mkString(",")) 
    }
```

### In Scala REPL:

```
scala> val list = List("1","10","12","30","40","50")
list: List[String] = List(1, 10, 12, 30, 40, 50)
scala> acc(list,"12")
res29: List[java.io.Serializable] = List(1, 10, 12, List(30,40,50))

scala> acc(list,"10")
res30: List[java.io.Serializable] = List(1, 10, List(12,30,40,50))

scala> acc(list,"40")
res31: List[java.io.Serializable] = List(1, 10, 12, 30, 40, List(50))

scala> acc(list,"30")
res32: List[java.io.Serializable] = List(1, 10, 12, 30, List(40,50))
```